# Why doesn't "mar" argument to plot.default get used?

Tags: r, plot, graphics

Looking at the help file for `plot.default`, specifically the section on `...`, I'd expect that supplying an argument `mar=c(1,1,1,1)` would lead to it being used for the current plot. Is there a way to set the margins just for the current plot like this, and where in the help system should I have looked to answer the problem?

Consider the example:

```
#R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03) -- "Supposedly Educational"
#Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
#Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
#...

#Defaults
par("mar")
#[1] 5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1

#Example 1 - plot using default parameters
plot(1)
savePlot("example1.png",type="png")
```

[image: Example 1 - large margin]

```
#Example 2 - specify parameters as extra arguments
plot(1, mar=c(1,1,1,1))
savePlot("example2.png",type="png")
```

[image: Example 2 - large margin]

```
#Example 3 - specify margins, then plot
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
plot(1)
savePlot("example3.png",type="png")
```

[image: Example 3 - small margin]

I'd expect Example 2 to produce the same output as Example 3, but instead it produces the same output as Example 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several parameters can only be set by a call to ‘par()’:

```
    • ‘"ask"’,

    • ‘"fig"’, ‘"fin"’,

    • ‘"lheight"’,

    • ‘"mai"’, ‘"mar"’, ‘"mex"’, ‘"mfcol"’, ‘"mfrow"’, ‘"mfg"’,

    • ‘"new"’,

    • ‘"oma"’, ‘"omd"’, ‘"omi"’,

    • ‘"pin"’, ‘"plt"’, ‘"ps"’, ‘"pty"’,

    • ‘"usr"’,

    • ‘"xlog"’, ‘"ylog"’,

    • ‘"ylbias"’
```

The `...` in `plot.default` is passed to functions called within `plot.default`; there is no chance that global parameters like `mar` could be used.